# 3D Diagram with conditional formatting colours in the background of numerical values

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

I want to create a diagram with Texmaker and pgfplots/Tikz (or any other package which is helpful). I have several measuring values at different positions. The axes should show the position in x- and y-direction, therefore I don't have an own axis for the target value (density).

In the diagram, the measured values should be shown at the correct position, and have a coloured background. The colour has to correspond to a conditional formatting.

The coloured background shouldn't just be a simple box, but a cube.The cube's edge has to point upwards and the edge length has to be adjustable.

Honestly, I have absolutely no idea how to do that.

Comment: I personally think that you should try yourself before you ask such a complex question. Break the task into several simple questions and post them here if you do not succeed after reading the pgfplots manual (at least screen the example diagrams)  or searching this site.